# In the formula of capacitance of a conductor the $V$ is potential of conductor once fully charged or initial potential of conductor used to charge it

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage, capacitance

capacitance $C=q/V$
The $V$ here is the final potential of the conductor which is to be charged or the initial potential of the source conductor? We are not charging it by using a battery rather through conduction

Comment: $V$ is the potential difference across the plates of the capacitor and $q$ is the charge stored.